# How to get first element by XPath in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xpath, xmltype

In my Oracle db I have records like this one:

```
<ROOT>
  <Event>
    <Type>sldkfvjhkljh</Type>
    <ID>591252</ID>
  </Event>
  <Data>
    <File>
      <Name>1418688.pdf</Name>
      <URL>/591252/1418688.pdf</URL>
    </File>
    <File>
      <Name>1418688.xml</Name>
      <URL>/591252/1418688.xml</URL>
    </File>
  </Data>
</ROOT>
```

I need to extract a value from the first `<Name>` tag. If I try:

```
Select xmltype(xml_data).extract('//Name[1]/text()').getStringVal() from MY_TABLE
```

I get:

> 1418688.pdf1418688.xml

Why is that and how can I get just `1418688.pdf`?

Oracle Version:

> Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition
>   Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi

Comment: Just wondering, what do you get from xpath //File[1]/Name/text() ? I think that both Name elements are #1, because in their nodes they are each first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that both Name elements are #1 in this doc, because in their nodes they are each first. Try `//File[1]/Name/text()`

Comment: //File[last()]/Name/text() should work in that case.